# Getting dpkg error in 20.04.5 LTS version

Tags: apt, server, dpkg, mysql

Getting this error everytime I'm trying to install anything.

Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...

```
/usr/lib/mecab/mecab-dict-index: error while loading shared libraries: libmecab.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mecab-ipadic (--configure):
 installed mecab-ipadic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mecab-ipadic-utf8:
 mecab-ipadic-utf8 depends on mecab-ipadic; however:
  Package mecab-ipadic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mecab-ipadic-utf8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mecab-ipadic
 mecab-ipadic-utf8
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Two things. 1. What version of Ubuntu are you using? 2. You need to deal with the dependencies.

Comment: Are you installing packages with `dpkg`? If yes, then you need to take care of dependencies manually. This is why it's recommended to use `apt`, which handles dependencies for you.

Comment: "*error while loading shared libraries: libmecab.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*" strongly suggests that the `libmecab2` package is missing. Install it. Curious what command or instructions you are using to install, since `apt` should normally install all dependencies (like libmecab2) for you automatically.